# reportlab vertical codebar code39

Tags: python, reportlab

Beginning with reportlab with python, final step of my little medical app.

I can't find a working solution for setting up a vertical barcode in a Frame designed for it (side thin frame). Everything else is ok (the document is composed of five frames, tables, other barcodes).
Perhaps the frame is useless, but how can i do this ?

Ideas ?
Thanks.

Here is my horrible code, sorry for that, i'm studying it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Frame, PageTemplate, BaseDocTemplate, FrameBreak, Table, TableStyle, KeepInFrame
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code39 
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.platypus.flowables import Flowable
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.lib.units import cm
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER, TA_RIGHT
from reportlab.lib.colors import black, purple, white, yellow, blue, darkblue

class verticalText(Flowable):
    ''' Rotate a text in a tabe cell '''
    def __init__(self, text):
        Flowable.__init__(self)
        self.text = text

    def draw(self):
        canvas = self.canv
        canvas.rotate(90)
        #fs = canvas._fontsize
        #canvas.translate(1, -fs/1.2)
        canvas.drawString(0, -1, self.text)

    #def wrap(self, aW, aH):
        #canv = self.canv
        #fn, fs = canv._fontname, canv._fontsize
        #return canv._leading, 1 + canv.stringWidth(self.text, fn ,fs)

class pdf():
    def __init__(self, _filename, _lignes_redigees):

        #VERROUS
        self.verBIZONE = False

        #PREPARATION DES DONNES TRANSMISES
        self.lignes_redigees = _lignes_redigees

        rpps = "10100167890"
        noordo = "20170524130651"

        #code barres rpps
        self.rpps_barcode = code39.Extended39(rpps)
        #code barre ordo
        self.noordo_barcode = code39.Extended39(noordo+rpps)


        vdoc = [['TITRE PRENOM NOM'], 
                ['DATADATADATADATADATADATADATADATA'], 
                ['DATADATADATADATADATADATADATADATA'],
                ['DATADATADATADATADATADATADATADATADATADATADATADATA'],
                [self.rpps_barcode],
                ['DATADATADATADATADATADATADATADATA']]

        vpat = [["TITRE PRENOM NOM"], ["DATADATADATADATADATADATADATADATA"], ["DATADATADATADATA"]]

        self.data_datelieu = "Toulouse, le 22 mai 2017"
        self.__preparation_des_data_lignes_redigees()

        # PDF Properties
        self.Title = "Ordonnance"
        self.Author = "DATADATADATADATA"
        self.PageInfo = "-"
        p_h = 29.7 #page height
        p_w = 21   #page width
        h_m = 1    #marges hauteur
        w_m = 1    #marges largeur
        entetes_h = 5.3
        datelieu_h = 1

        #coo frame Side
        side_x1 = w_m; side_y1 = h_m; side_h = p_h - 2*h_m ; side_w = 1
        #coo frame doc
        doc_x1 = side_x1 + side_w ; doc_y1 = p_h - h_m - entetes_h ; doc_w = (p_w - 2*w_m - side_w)/2 ; doc_h = entetes_h
        #coo frame pat
        pat_x1 = side_x1 + side_w + doc_w ; pat_y1 = p_h - h_m - entetes_h ; pat_w = doc_w ; pat_h = doc_h
        #coo frame date lieu
        dl_x1 = side_w + w_m ; dl_y1 = p_h - h_m - entetes_h - datelieu_h ; dl_w = p_w - 2*w_m - side_w; dl_h = datelieu_h 
        #coo frame pres
        pr_x1 = side_w + w_m ; pr_y1 = h_m ; pr_w = dl_w; pr_h = p_h - 2*h_m - entetes_h - datelieu_h
        self.pres_w = pr_w

        # define frames - for frames in page
        self.frSide = Frame(x1=side_x1*cm, y1=side_y1*cm, width=side_w*cm, height=side_h*cm, 
                            leftPadding=0, rightPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        self.frMedecin = Frame(x1=doc_x1*cm, y1=doc_y1*cm, width=doc_w*cm, height=doc_h*cm, showBoundary=1,
                            leftPadding=0, rightPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        self.frPatient = Frame(x1=pat_x1*cm, y1=pat_y1*cm, width=pat_w*cm, height=pat_h*cm, 
                            leftPadding=0, rightPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        self.frDateLieu = Frame(x1=dl_x1*cm, y1=dl_y1*cm, width=dl_w*cm, height=dl_h*cm, 
                            leftPadding=0, rightPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)
        self.frPres = Frame(x1=pr_x1*cm, y1=pr_y1*cm, width=pr_w*cm, height=pr_h*cm, 
                            leftPadding=0, rightPadding=0, topPadding=0, bottomPadding=0)

        # define pageTemplates - for page in document
        self.mainPage = PageTemplate(pagesize=A4, frames=[self.frSide, self.frMedecin, self.frPatient, self.frDateLieu,
                                                          self.frPres])

        # define BasicDocTemplate - for document
        self.doc = BaseDocTemplate(_filename, pagesize=A4, pageTemplates=self.mainPage, title=self.Title,
                                   author=self.Author, showBoundary=0)

        # styles
        self.styles = self.__init_stylesheet()
        self.standard_styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        self.stylePat = self.standard_styles['Normal']
        # i don't use it, not more than paragraphs
        self.styleDoc = ParagraphStyle('hdoc')
        self.styleDoc.defaults['borderColor'] = '#000000'
        self.styleDoc.defaults['borderWidth'] = '1'

        self.styleDL = self.styles['hdatelieu']

        #create tables
        self.doc_table = Table(vdoc, colWidths=doc_w*cm)
        self.doc_table.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'CENTER'),
                                       ('TEXTCOLOR', (0,0), (-1,-1), darkblue),
                                       ('FONT', (0,0), (0,0),'Times-Bold', 15),
                                       ('FONT', (0,1), (-1,-1), 'Times-Roman', 13)]))
        self.pat_table = Table(vpat, colWidths=pat_w*cm, vAlign='TOP')
        self.pat_table.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'CENTER'),
                                       ('TEXTCOLOR', (0,0), (-1,-1), black),
                                       ('FONT', (0,1), (-1,-1), 'Courier-Bold', 11),
                                       ('FONT', (0,0), (0,0), 'Courier-Bold', 13)]))

        #preparing prescription tables
        self.__prepare_les_séparateurs_ald()
        self.__preparation_des_tables_de_ligne()

        #process
        self._process()     

    def __init_stylesheet(self): #i don't use it, not more than paragraphs, it was for studying
        styles= {'default': ParagraphStyle('default',
                                            fontName='Times-Roman',
                                            fontSize=10,
                                            leading=12,
                                            leftIndent=0,
                                            rightIndent=0,
                                            firstLineIndent=0,
                                            alignment=TA_LEFT,
                                            spaceBefore=0,
                                            spaceAfter=0,
                                            bulletFontName='Times-Roman',
                                            bulletFontSize=10,
                                            bulletIndent=0,
                                            textColor= black,
                                            backColor=None,
                                            wordWrap=None,
                                            borderWidth= 0,
                                            borderPadding= 0,
                                            borderColor= None,
                                            borderRadius= None,
                                            allowWidows= 1,
                                            allowOrphans= 0,
                                            textTransform=None,  # 'uppercase' | 'lowercase' | None
                                            endDots=None,         
                                            splitLongWords=1,
                                        )}

        styles['hdoc'] = ParagraphStyle('hdoc', parent=styles['default'],
            fontName='Helvetica-Bold',
            fontSize=12,
            leading = 17,
            borderColor=black,
            borderWidth=1, 
            borderPadding = 0.5*cm,
            alignment=TA_CENTER,
            wordWrap = 'LTR',
            textColor=darkblue)

        styles['hpat'] = ParagraphStyle('hpat', parent=styles['default'],
            fontName='Helvetica',
            fontSize=12,
            alignment=TA_CENTER,
            textColor=black)

        styles['hdatelieu'] = ParagraphStyle('hdatelieu', parent=styles['default'],
            fontName='Helvetica',
            fontSize=12,
            alignment=TA_RIGHT,
            borderColor=black,
            borderWidth=1,            
            borderPadding = 0,
            textColor=black)        

        return styles


    def __prepare_les_séparateurs_ald(self):

        p_ald = [["Prescription(s) relative(s) au traitement de l'affection de longue durée reconnue, (liste ou hors liste)"],
                 ["(AFFECTION EXONERANTE)"]]
        p_nald = [["Prescription(s) SANS RAPPORT avec l'affection de longue durée"],
                  ["(MALADIES INTERRECURRENTES)"]]

        self.t_ald = Table(p_ald, colWidths=self.pres_w*cm)
        self.t_ald.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'CENTER'),
                                   ('VALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'MIDDLE'),
                                   ('TEXTCOLOR', (0,0), (-1,-1), black),
                                   ('FONT', (0,0), (-1,-1),'Helvetica', 11),
                                   ('LINEABOVE', (0,0), (0,0), 1, black),
                                   ('LINEBELOW', (-1,-1), (-1,-1), 1, black)]))

        self.t_nald = Table(p_nald, colWidths=self.pres_w*cm)
        self.t_nald.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'CENTER'),
                                   ('VALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'MIDDLE'),
                                   ('TEXTCOLOR', (0,0), (-1,-1), black),
                                   ('FONT', (0,0), (-1,-1),'Helvetica', 11),
                                   ('LINEABOVE', (0,0), (0,0), 1, black),
                                   ('LINEBELOW', (-1,-1), (-1,-1), 1, black)]))

    def __preparation_des_data_lignes_redigees(self):
        #prepare data for platypus tables
        self.data_lignes_redigees = []

        #first look for ALD prescription
        for ligne in self.lignes_redigees:
            if ligne[-1] == 'A.L.D.':
                self.verBIZONE = True


        if self.verBIZONE == False :
            x = 0
            for ligne in self.lignes_redigees:
                x +=1 
                bloc_data=[]
                i=0
                for item in ligne:
                    i += 1
                    if i == 1 : j = str(x)+'.'
                    else : j = ""
                    bloc_data.append([j,item])
                self.data_lignes_redigees.append(bloc_data)
                print('blocdata', self.data_lignes_redigees)

        else:
            self.data_lignes_redigees_ald = []
            self.data_lignes_redigees_nald = []

            x = 0
            for ligne in self.lignes_redigees:
                if ligne[-1] == 'A.L.D.':
                    x +=1 
                    bloc_data=[]
                    i=0
                    for item in ligne:
                        i += 1
                        if i == 1 : j = str(x)+'.'
                        else : j = ""
                        if item != 'A.L.D.': bloc_data.append([j,item])
                    self.data_lignes_redigees_ald.append(bloc_data)
                    print('blocdata_ald', self.data_lignes_redigees_ald) 

            for ligne in self.lignes_redigees:
                if ligne[-1] != 'A.L.D.':
                    x +=1 
                    bloc_data=[]
                    i=0
                    for item in ligne:
                        i += 1
                        if i == 1 : j = str(x)+'.'
                        else : j = ""
                        bloc_data.append([j,item])
                    self.data_lignes_redigees_nald.append(bloc_data)
                    print('blocdata_ald', self.data_lignes_redigees_nald)


    def __preparation_des_tables_de_ligne(self):               
        #prepare les tables

        self.story_tables_pres = []
        self.story_tables_pres_ald = []

        if self.verBIZONE == False:
            for data_ligne in self.data_lignes_redigees:
                tablep = Table(data_ligne, 
                               colWidths=(1*cm, self.pres_w*cm - 1*cm),
                               rowHeights = [1*cm] + [0.5*cm]*(len(data_ligne)-1))

                tablep.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'LEFT'),
                                            ('ALIGN', (0,0), (0,-1), 'RIGHT'),
                                           ('TEXTCOLOR', (0,0), (-1,-1), black),
                                           ('FONT', (0,0), (-1,0),'Helvetica-Bold', 12),
                                           ('FONT', (0,1), (-1,-1), 'Helvetica', 11)]))

                self.story_tables_pres.append(tablep)

        if self.verBIZONE == True:
            for data_ligne in self.data_lignes_redigees_ald:
                tablep = Table(data_ligne, 
                               colWidths=(1*cm, self.pres_w*cm - 1*cm),
                               rowHeights = [1*cm] + [0.5*cm]*(len(data_ligne)-1))

                tablep.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'LEFT'),
                                            ('ALIGN', (0,0), (0,-1), 'RIGHT'),
                                           ('TEXTCOLOR', (0,0), (-1,-1), black),
                                           ('FONT', (0,0), (-1,0),'Helvetica-Bold', 12),
                                           ('FONT', (0,1), (-1,-1), 'Helvetica', 11)]))

                self.story_tables_pres_ald.append(tablep)

            for data_ligne in self.data_lignes_redigees_nald:
                tablep = Table(data_ligne, 
                               colWidths=(1*cm, self.pres_w*cm - 1*cm),
                               rowHeights = [1*cm] + [0.5*cm]*(len(data_ligne)-1))

                tablep.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'LEFT'),
                                            ('ALIGN', (0,0), (0,-1), 'RIGHT'),
                                           ('TEXTCOLOR', (0,0), (-1,-1), black),
                                           ('FONT', (0,0), (-1,0),'Helvetica-Bold', 12),
                                           ('FONT', (0,1), (-1,-1), 'Helvetica', 11)]))

                self.story_tables_pres.append(tablep)




    def _process(self):

        #Story
        self.story = []
        #self.story.append(verticalText(self.noordo_barcode))
        self.story.append(FrameBreak())


        self.kept_doc_st = []
        self.kept_doc_st.append(self.doc_table)
        kept_doc = KeepInFrame(0,0 ,self.kept_doc_st, mode='shrink', hAlign='CENTER', vAlign='MIDDLE', fakeWidth=False)

        self.story.append(kept_doc)
        self.story.append(FrameBreak())

        self.kept_pat_st = []
        self.kept_pat_st.append(self.pat_table)
        kept_pat = KeepInFrame(0,0 ,self.kept_pat_st, mode='shrink', hAlign='CENTER', vAlign='MIDDLE', fakeWidth=False)

        self.story.append(kept_pat)
        self.story.append(FrameBreak())

        hd = Table([[self.data_datelieu]], colWidths=self.pres_w*cm, rowHeights=1*cm)
        hd.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'RIGHT'),
                                ('TEXTCOLOR', (0,0), (-1,-1), black),
                                ('FONT', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'Courier-Bold', 11),
                                ('VALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'MIDDLE')]))
        self.story.append(hd)
        self.story.append(FrameBreak())


        #mise en place du bloc de prescription
        if self.verBIZONE == False:
            for e in self.story_tables_pres:
                self.story.append(e)
        if self.verBIZONE == True:
            self.story.append(self.t_ald)
            for e in self.story_tables_pres_ald:
                self.story.append(e)
            self.story.append(self.t_nald)
            for e in self.story_tables_pres:
                self.story.append(e)            


        #finallement
        self.doc.build(self.story)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    lignes=[['(cétirizine), 10 mg, cp', 'Prendre 1 cp le matin', 'A.L.D.'],
            ['DEROXAT (paroxétine), 20 mg, cp', 'Si besoin prendre 1 cp le matin', 'si envie', 'A.L.D.']]


    app = pdf('test.pdf', lignes)
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i managed to make some bricolage with this:

http://nullege.com/codes/search/reportlab.graphics.barcode.createBarcodeDrawing

Instead of using a Text-and-Font-made-Barcode, i turned it into a drawing easy to rotate (rotate method).

Answer (score 0):

That was surprisingly easy. You just need to rotate and translate the canvas underneath the barcode and swap its width and height. For that reason, I inherited the original class and changed the `wrap` and `draw` methods.

```
from reportlab.graphics.barcode.code39 import Extended39


class VerticalCode39(Extended39):
    def wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
        w, h = super().wrap(*args, **kwargs)
        return h, w

    def draw(self):
        self.canv.rotate(90)
        self.canv.translate(0, -self.barHeight)
        super().draw()
```

The usage of `VerticalCode39` is the same as of `Extended39`.